# How to convert object to string array in android

Tags: java, android

Hi in this code friend value returning an object.but i want to return to return string array with value.
while debugging it giving like this 
`[at.vcity.androidim.types.FriendInfo@b2e758d8, at.vcity.androidim.types.FriendInfo@b2e6d160]`
**java**

FriendInfo[] friend=FriendController.getFriendsInfo();

**friendinfo.java**

```
public class FriendInfo{




        public static final String FRIEND_LIST = "friendList";
        public static final String USERNAME = "username";
        public static final String IP = "IP";
        public static final String PORT = "port";
        public static final String USER_KEY = "userKey";
        public static final String MESSAGE = "message";  
        public static final String STATUS = "status";
        final boolean[] checked = null;

        public STATUS status;

        public String userName;
        public String ip;
        public String port;
        public String userKey;
        public String expire;


};
```

Comment: override the toString() function within the object class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override `toString()`

For instance

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return userName;
}
```